# Optimizing MySQL query with a composite index

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a table which currently has about 80 million rows, created as follows:

```
create table records
(
  id      int auto_increment primary key,
  created int             not null,
  status  int default '0' not null
)
  collate = utf8_unicode_ci;

create index created_and_status_idx
  on records (created, status);
```

The created column contains unix timestamps and status can be an integer between -10 and 10. The records are evenly distributed regarding the created date, and around half of them are of status 0 or -10.

I have a cron that selects records that are between 32 and 8 days old, processes them and then deletes them, for certain statuses. The query is as follows:

```
SELECT
    records.id
FROM records
WHERE
    (records.status = 0 OR records.status = -10)
    AND records.created BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 32 * 86400 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 8 * 86400
LIMIT 500
```

The query was fast when the records were at the beginning of the creation interval, but now that the cleanup reaches the records at the end of interval it takes about 10 seconds to run. Explaining the query says it uses the index, but it parses about 40 million records.

My question is if there is anything I can do to improve the performance of the query, and if so, how exactly.

Thank you.

Comment: did you try using two indexes ? I don't understand your choice on a composite one .

Comment: Your index is (created, status) and you're querying for status, created. Try reversing the conditions in your query. Also, post output of EXPLAIN.

Comment: How many records match the between 8 and 32 days and earlier than 32 days? If you do not have data earlier than 32 days then index is of no use.

Comment: @DamirKasipovic I am sure MySQL knows that reversing the conditions does not make a difference.

Comment: Side question: why not just select everything older than 8 days ago?  You're running this continually.  Especially since, if the Cron process runs only once a month, due to timing differences you could be ignoring/dropping records.  Also, the use of `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` means you're taking the current time into account, which may or may not be what you want?  And for sure, the `BETWEEN` clause means that your upper limit is actually 7:23:59 seconds ago, not the full 8 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `union all` is your best approach:

```
(SELECT r.id
 FROM records r
 WHERE r.status = 0 AND
       r.created BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 32 * 86400 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 8 * 86400
 LIMIT 500
) UNION ALL
(SELECT r.id
 FROM records r
 WHERE r.status = -10 AND
       r.created BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 32 * 86400 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 8 * 86400
 LIMIT 500
) 
LIMIT 500;
```

This can use an index on `records(status, created, id)`. 
 Note:  use `union` if `records.id` could have duplicates.

You are also using `LIMIT` with no `ORDER BY`.  That is generally discouraged.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to reduce the query from about 10 seconds to 1-2 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Your index is in the wrong order.  You should put the `IN` column (`status`) first (you phrased it as an `OR`), and put the 'range' column (`created`) last:

```
INDEX(status, created)
```

(Don't give me any guff about "cardinality"; we are not looking at individual columns.)

Are there really only 3 columns in the table?  Do you need `id`?  If not, get rid of it and change to

```
PRIMARY KEY(status, created)
```

Other [*techniques*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig) for walking through large tables efficiently.